# add a property to an array of elements based on matching set on props - es6

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have the following array of objects:

```
 arr = [
   {
      connectors:[
         {source: "aaaa", target: "bbbb"}
         {source: "bbbb", target: "2222"}
         {source: "aaaa", target: "cccc"}
         {source: "cccc", target: "1111"}
      ],
      connections: [
         {name: "aaaa", id: "11", type: "main"}
         {name: "bbbb", id: "22", type: "submain"}
         {name: "2222", id: "33", type: "supersubmain"}
         {name: "cccc", id: "44", type: "submain"}
         {name: "1111", id: "55", type: "supersubmain"}
      ]
   }
]
```

I need to add an extra property to the array based on matching key-val pairs to the connectors array.

The condition would mainly be `if(connectors.source === connections.name && connections.type === 'main')`, then i need to add the connect property to the connectors array as shown below.

I want the following output:

```
 arr = [
       {
          connectors:[
             {source: "aaaa", target: "bbbb", connect: true}
             {source: "bbbb", target: "2222", connect: false}
             {source: "aaaa", target: "cccc", connect: true}
             {source: "cccc", target: "1111", connect: false}
          ],
          connections: [
             {name: "aaaa", id: "11", type: "main"}
             {name: "bbbb", id: "22", type: "submain"}
             {name: "2222", id: "33", type: "supersubmain"}
             {name: "cccc", id: "44", type: "submain"}
             {name: "1111", id: "55", type: "supersubmain"}
          ]
       }
    ]
```

I have tried using a combo of different es6 functions like map,filter,spreadable but cant find the appropriate solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `forEach()` to loop each object and `some` to check for condition and add `connect` value.

```js
var arr = [{"connectors":[{"source":"aaaa","target":"bbbb"},{"source":"bbbb","target":"2222"},{"source":"aaaa","target":"cccc"},{"source":"cccc","target":"1111"}],"connections":[{"name":"aaaa","id":"11","type":"main"},{"name":"bbbb","id":"22","type":"submain"},{"name":"2222","id":"33","type":"supersubmain"},{"name":"cccc","id":"44","type":"submain"},{"name":"1111","id":"55","type":"supersubmain"}]}]

arr.forEach(function(c) {
  c.connectors.forEach(function(a) {
    var connect = c.connections.some(function(e) {
      return e.name == a.source && e.type == 'main'
    })
    a.connect = connect;
  })
})


console.log(arr)
```

Comment: + for some... Not used enough in my opinion.

Comment: I must say that this approach has one downside: it will iterate though all items of `c.connections` array if it doesn't find `e.type == 'main'`. The sequence of numbers of internal iterations will be `1`, `5`, `1`, `5`, while it could be `1`, `2`, `1`, `4` after some optimization

Comment: With assumption that there could be multiple items with same name and different type.

Answer (score 1):

Try a combination of `.forEach()` and `.some()` methods:

```
arr[0].connectors.forEach(c => Object.assign(c, {
  connect: arr[0].connections.some(i => i.name === c.source && i.type === 'main')
}));
```

---

Or with `.map()` and spread operator (requires an assignment `arr[0].connectors = ...`):

```
arr[0].connectors = arr[0].connectors.map(c => ({...c,
  connect: arr[0].connections.some(i => i.name === c.source && i.type === 'main')
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

With `Array.forEach()` and `Array.some()` functions:

```js
var arr = [{"connectors":[{"source":"aaaa","target":"bbbb"},{"source":"bbbb","target":"2222"},{"source":"aaaa","target":"cccc"},{"source":"cccc","target":"1111"}],"connections":[{"name":"aaaa","id":"11","type":"main"},{"name":"bbbb","id":"22","type":"submain"},{"name":"2222","id":"33","type":"supersubmain"},{"name":"cccc","id":"44","type":"submain"},{"name":"1111","id":"55","type":"supersubmain"}]}],
    curr_obj;   // auxiliary stub(for matched object)

arr[0].connectors.forEach(function(o){
    o['connect'] = arr[0].connections.some(function(i){
        curr_obj = i;
        return i.name === o.source;
    }) && curr_obj.type == "main";
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
arr[0].connectors.forEach(connector => {
    // If it can find a connection meeting the criteria then set connect to true
    if(arr[0].connections.some(connection => connection.name == connection.source && connection.type == 'main')){
        connector.connect = true;
    }
    else{
        connector.connect = false;
    }
});
```